# Does activemq static network of broker stop forwarding messages without advisorySupport enabled?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, cluster-computing, broker

I have set up a network of brokers exactly as per [this post](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-use-automatic-failover-in.html) of Bruce Snyder:

**Broker 1:**

```
<networkConnector name="amq1-nc"
uri="static:(tcp://localhost:61617)"
userName="system"
password="manager"
/>
```

**Broker 2:**

```
<networkConnector name="amq2-nc"
uri="static:(tcp://localhost:61616)"
userName="system"
password="manager"
/>
```

I have advisorySupport="false" in the broker tag of both the broker's config XML and started both the brokers.

Then I started the consumer using the command:

```
ant consumer -Durl=tcp://0.0.0.0:61616
```

and finally started producer using this command:

```
ant producer -Durl=tcp://0.0.0.0:61617
```

All the produced messaged then go in the pending state on the broker running on port 61617 and consumer connected on port 61616 broker never gets the messages.

Does the network of brokers stop forwarding messages without advisorySupport enabled? I thought that was fixed in a recent release. (I'm using activemq 5.4.2 release).

Does ActiveMQ static network of brokers stop forwarding messages advisorySupport is disabled?

**Update:**
I ran into issues using advisorySupport="false" and staticallyIncludedDestinations.

We use JMS for mostly request-response like described here: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

We are using a temporary queue on the Producer side to be able to receive response from Consumers and since staticallyIncludedDestinations cannot include these temporary queue names in it, therefore, all the Producers are unable to receive responses back from clients when advisorySupport is disabled.

I am coming to the conclusion that for our scenario advisorySupport cannot be turned off unless there is some other config trick I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation sais:

> "Warning:
>   Advisory messages are required for
>   dynamic network broker topologies as
>   NetworkConnectors subscribe to
>   advisory messages. In the absence of
>   advisories, a network must be
>   statically configured.

The Advisory messages tell a node where remote consumers are and therefore where to send incoming messages. WITHOUT them, you have to configure that stuff yourself.

The documentation has an example how to do that: http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

Comment: @Laures: I have read that document many times and now very well that  dynamic network brokers do need advisorySupport enabled. But if you read my question and title of this page again it says clearly that it is not working for **"static network of broker"**.

Comment: static doesn't end with broker discovery. The advisory messages tell a node where a consumer for queue A is. without them your config has to tell the node where to send any incoming messages for A. your config examples don't contain that information. In your case the staticallyIncludedDestinations element should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much Laures. Gary Tully also responded to my post on activemq mailing list today with same answer that broker config needs to have: 
    `<staticallyIncludedDestinations>
               <queue physicalName="TEST.FOO"/>
    </staticallyIncludedDestinations>` inside `networkConnector` tag.

Comment: I found another issue with turning off advisorySupport, please see my update above.

Comment: new trick: i will assume that all dynamic queues are named `dynamic.<something>.` Then `<dynamicallyIncludedDestinations><queue physicalName="dynamic.>"/>...` (thanks to the activemq wildcard mechanism) should forward all messages from queues that start with dynamic. through the networkConnector.

Comment: @Laures: I also thought of this trick but unfortunately these are temporary queues created like this: `Destination tempDest = session.createTemporaryQueue();` which doesn't give us any control in deciding the name of those temporary queue and hence we won't be able to use `<queue physicalName="dynamic.>"/>` directive.

Comment: i had a look at the activemq code. Unfortunately the name of a Temporary queue is a long number (i half expected something like tmp.<id>). The only idea (without coding inside activemq) I have left is that you explicitly create the destinations with a name. Since name generation is then clientbased there can be collisions, but you could use a common prefix and route.

Comment: @Laures: Problem with using named destination is that multiple instances of same Producer will use same name (unless we have per producer instance name; which is an operational hazard). If using same name then we'll have to use message selectors something we were consciously trying to avoid because of various reasons. There is a thread on activemq mailing list for this issue where I'm discussing this issue with Gary Tully: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/network-of-broker-stop-forwarding-messages-without-advisorySupport-enabled-td3386261.html